# Does Slick handle a collection like List/Set etc?

Tags: scala, slick, case-class

My question is:

My Scala's case class has parameters where a collection(i.e., List) is a part of its constructor parameters, and I wonder how to map my case class into Slick style database table or tables if necessary?

In other words, I would like to "Join tables in Slick way to map to a Json formatted case class, which is to be represented to the frontend (javascript) bits"?

Please kindly give me a shout if my question is not clear enough.

The same question is at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/QqZz_M-1VTg

For example,

```
case class ClassA (id: Int, lists: List[ClassB])

    object ClassA extends TableQuery(new ClassATable(_)) {

      // JSON formatter


        implicit val classAFormat: Format[ClassA] = (
            (JsPath \ "id").formatNullable[Int] and
              (JsPath \ "lists").format[List[ClassB]]
            )(ClassA.apply, unlift(ClassA.unapply))
        }


    case class ClassB (id: Int, name: String)

    object ClassB extends TableQuery(new ClassBTable(_)) {
    implicit val classBFormat: Format[ClassB] = (
                (JsPath \ "id").formatNullable[Int] and
                  (JsPath \ "name").format[String]
                )(ClassB.apply, unlift(ClassB.unapply))
            }
```

So, the missing bit is to create ClassATable and ClassBTable in such a way that there is a bi-directional relationship by means of each one's "id"?

Many thanks,

Comment: Kindly shouting. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have to work with existing classes or can you change them?

Comment: Also posted here https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/scalaquery/3b92aa7a-c854-4d3e-8865-96fe1612deca%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer !!

Comment: Classes can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class like this
`case class ClassA (id: Int, lists: List[ClassB])` implies that table B has to be loaded when Table A is loaded. This hard-codes the loading strategy. This is avoided in idiomatic Slick code. Instead, in Slick this is usually solved with tuples to make it more flexible. The Slick tables are then simply mapped to versions of ClassA and ClassB, which do NOT contain references to each other, only the column data. Instead, a join can produce a result of type `List[(ClassA,ClassB)]` and with a groupBy and map you get `(ClassA,List[ClassB])`. (Alternatively you get the same with two separate queries.) This is roughly what you want. Instead of a Tuple you can define a small `case class AWithBs(a: ClassA, bs: List[ClassB])` to associate them. You can `.map(AWithBs.apply)` to create them from the list of tuples.

Comment: What if it only makes sense to load table B while loading table A?

Comment: The reason being I want to hit only one endpoint which takes me to saving data only once, which in turn would save time/performance?

Comment: No change :). The Slick Tables describe your relational tables directly. Relationships should be handled using queries that join tables. They ARE the way how you "map" relationships in Slick. Store them in some var or def for re-use.

Comment: Hi Mr vogt, I wonder if you could kindly point me towards more resources (like github?) that relate to this topic? Thanks

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/JoinTest.scala A documentation chapter on the topic should become available around the end of June.